# Tweetinvi 4.0.1 AuthFlow.InitAuthentications returns null

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

C# implementation.  keys verified.  Callback urls in place in Twitter app configuration.

using version 4.0.1 and also the JsonLanguageConvertFix

```
private IAuthenticationContext _authenticationContext;

string TWcallbackURL = href_core_twitter + "?twcc=" + vCode;
var appCreds = new ConsumerCredentials(TWConsumerKey, TWConsumerKey_secret);
_authenticationContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(appCreds, TWcallbackURL);
if(_authenticationContext == null)
                    {
                        _url = "NO URL";
                        _status = "ERROR";
                        _authKey = "";
                        _authSecret = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _url = _authenticationContext.AuthorizationURL;
                        _authKey = _authenticationContext.Token.AuthorizationKey;
                        _authSecret = _authenticationContext.Token.AuthorizationSecret;
                        _status = "OK";
                    }
```

_authenticationContext is always null no matter what I have tried.  This code was working correctly about a week or so ago.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the security protocol.  The following is needed:

```
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                                        | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                                        | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                                        | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

all is working now.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend! I have been struggling with this issue for a while now!

Comment: Looks like the code works for a while and errors out again in a few minutes, even after adding this piece of code. Is your application running fine consistently?